# Child component is not getting data from the parent component

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

In React I cannot get the Child component to receive data from the parent component.
While logging data variable in app.js it shows what it should show, in the Child component I am getting the error that cannot read map of undefined and logging it inside Child component returns undefined because there is nothing inside

Code in App.js

```
const [data, setData] = useState(0);

useEffect((loading) => {
  const data = array.map((item) => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const value = await getValue(item);
      setData((prev) => [...prev, value]);
    };
    return getData();
  });
}, []);
console.log('data', data); // all good inside app.js

return (
  <>
    <Child data={data} />
  </>
);
```

and this is the Child component:

```
export default function Child({ data }) {
  console.log(data); //nothing
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <div>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [data, setData] = useState(0);
```

is supposed to be

```
const [data, setData] = useState([0]);
```

Since if `data` is a number initially, `data.map` inside `Child` wouldn't work.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-lamarr-mher3?file=/src/App.js)